# Log4j2 separate log files by module name

Tags: java, logging, wildcard, log4j2

I want to write log files based on module name. 
for ex. 
one log file for user management module and 
one for products module etc.

My project package structure looks like below;

```
com.mycompany.service.user
com.mycompany.service.product
com.mycompany.controller.user
com.mycompany.controller.product
...
```

I want to write log messages from 
`com.mycompany.*.user` *(com.mycompany.service.user and com.mycompany.controller.user)* to `com.mycompany.user.log` file, 
and `com.mycompany.*.product` to `com.mycompany.user.log` file.

I know I can create loggers like bellow

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.service.user" level="INFO">
  <AppenderRef ref="AppenderUsers" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.mycompany.controller.user" level="INFO">
  <AppenderRef ref="AppenderUsers" />
</logger>
...
```

But this way I have to add so many loggers.
Cant I use wildcard `*` or `**` or regex to logger name somethihng like this?

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.*.user" level="INFO">
  <AppenderRef ref="AppenderUsers" />
</logger>
```

Or is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have solved this by writing a Custom Filter Plugin.
I have used same approach used in [Regex](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter) filter. But Regex filter, match given regex with Message content. But I have written a filter to match regex with class name.

I have describe this in my blog post. http://rohithag.blogspot.com/

Comment: Your blogpost is helpful, but did you ever submit a feature request to log4j2?

Comment: For future visitors, the full link is: http://rohithag.blogspot.fr/2014/12/log4j-2-separate-log-files-by-modules.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you raise this as a feature request in the log4j2 Jira issue tracker.