# Log4j2 Using class/logger name as a pattern for RoutingAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am trying to set up individual logging files per class in a certain package. The closest solution I've found is to use the RoutingAppender and to have a special getLogger for those certain classes that adds to a ThreadContext when that getLogger method is called. However, this solution isn't creating any new log files.  I've been reading stackoverflow entries and log4j2 documentation, but can't understand where I'm going wrong. Here's some of entries/documentation that I've looked at

- [Log4j2: Dynamic creation of log files for multiple logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052070/log4j2-dynamic-creation-of-log-files-for-multiple-logs)
- [How to write different logs in different files with log4j2 (MDC in xml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827923/how-to-write-different-logs-in-different-files-with-log4j2-mdc-in-xml)
- [Log4j2 separate log files by module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951682/log4j2-separate-log-files-by-module-name)
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#ContextMapLookup

Can anyone help me understand why I don't have any of the className log files?

Here's the relevant excepts from my log4j2.xml:

```
    <Routing name="Routing">
        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:className}">
            <Route>
                <File name="testCaseLog"
                    fileName="${ctx:className}.log">
                    <PatternLayout
                        pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
                </File>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    (other loggers)
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="stdout" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Routing"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Here's the bit from my logger function in a myUtils class

```
public static Logger getLogger(String className) {
    ThreadContext.put("className", className);

    //This is using the slf4j LoggerFactory. I'm starting to think this might be the problem, but I can't get away from slf4j
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(className);

    return log;
}
```

Here's a call from within one of the classes that needs it's own log file:

```
    private final static Logger log = myUtils.getLogger(OpenTest.class.getName());
```

Comment: You are logging at INFO level? The appender will not receive TRACE and DEBUG log events with this config... Also, is the `<Root>` element nested within a `<Loggers>` containing element?

Comment: I can change the log level, but most of our uses are at the info level. I can see in the Console that there ARE comments from the classes that call myUtils.getLogger, but there isn't an appropriate file. The Root logger is within the <Loggers> </Loggers> element. Our configuration has other Loggers that I didn't think were related.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding another Route section to the Routes element you already have, with key="$${ctx:className}"?

```
        <Route key="$${ctx:className}">
            <File name="testCaseLog"
                fileName="${ctx:className}.log">
                <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n" />
            </File>
        </Route>
```